# How to change the fieldCls of a textfield dynamically in extjs?

Tags: extjs, textfield

In our application we have a textfield and a checkbox. By default textfield should be readonly. Whenever check box is checked, textfield should be editable.

We are able to do the above mentioned requirement. But we also have to show textfield in such a way that users should feel they can not edit it, when it is read only.

We used the below code for this:

```
{
   xtype:'textfield',
   id:'textfieldid',
   readOnly:true,
   fieldCls:'x-item-disabled'
    ...
}


{
    xtype:'checkbox',
    listeners:{
        change:function(thisCmp,newValue,oldValue){
                if(newValue==true){
                    Ext.getCmp('textfieldid').addCls('x-item-disabled');
                } else {
                    Ext.getCmp('textfieldid').removeCls('x-item-disabled');
                }
            }
    }
}
```

But some how i am not able to get it working.

Could anyone please suggest the way to solve it?

Actually I need to submit that field. If it is disabled, that field will not be submitted. So I tried with setting fieldCls dynamically.

Comment: This code is so bad mang.

Comment: The code is edited now.

Comment: else(newValue==true) http://i.imgur.com/c9Ups.gif

Comment: thanks for identifying it. It was copied by mistake. Actually while running the code it was not there. removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't you use `setDisabled` method of `Ext.form.field.Text`?

```
{
    xtype:'checkbox',
    listeners:{
        change:function(thisCmp,newValue,oldValue){
             Ext.getCmp('textfieldid').setDisabled(newValue);
        }
    }
}
```

and also don't specify `fieldCls:'x-item-disabled'` as config for TextField that will be automatically managed by `setDisabled` method, and if you want to initially render text field as disabled then you can use `disabled : true` in config like this

```
{
   xtype:'textfield',
   id:'textfieldid',
   disabled: true
    ...
}
```

**Another Option:**

you are initially using fieldCls property to specify disable class which can be wrong instead you could do something like this

```
{
   xtype:'textfield',
   id:'textfieldid',
   readOnly:true,
   listeners : {
       afterrender : function() {
            this.addCls('x-item-disabled');
       },
       scope : this
   }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Actually I need to submit that field. If it is disabled, that field will not be submitted. So I tried with setting fieldCls dynamically.

Comment: Thank you SilentSakky. I tried your second option this.addCls('x-item-disabled');. It is working fine.

Comment: good that it worked for you can mark the answer as complete, if your problem is fully solved